# Flutter how can wait return of function that in widget state

Tags: android, flutter

The application I made is simply listed switches.
I'm pulling the data from the database, when the data comes, it comes with future.buildr and the switches seem to be open or closed according to the incoming data. I return the status of this on or off with the function initialLabelindex: but every time I close and open the application, the initialLabelIndex returns null when I first enter this list tab, so the empty list returns and when I press this tab again, it loads correctly. I tried a lot and none of them worked, can anyone give an idea?
I'm sure I can pull the data every time I get statuscode 200

```
(  int initialLabelindex(int index,List<ActivityList> show) {
int? x;

  SmartTools.lightsInstance[0].forEach((element) {
    if(element.Id==show[index].Id){
       x=element.Status;
    }
  });
  return x!;
```

})

```
ToggleSwitch(
                                              minWidth: 50,
                                              minHeight: 42,
                                              animationDuration: 300,
                                              initialLabelIndex:initialLabelindex(index, show),
                                              cornerRadius: 10.0,
                                              activeFgColor: Colors.white,
                                              inactiveBgColor: Colors.grey,
                                              inactiveFgColor: Colors.white,
                                              totalSwitches: 2,
                                              icons: [
                                                show[index].GroupFriendlyName == 'Aydınlatma'
                                                    ? FontAwesomeIcons.lightbulb
                                                    : FontAwesomeIcons.sun,
                                                show[index].GroupFriendlyName == 'Aydınlatma'
                                                    ? FontAwesomeIcons.solidLightbulb
                                                    : FontAwesomeIcons.solidSun,
                                              ],
                                              iconSize: 30.0,
                                              activeBgColors: [
                                                const [Colors.black45, Colors.black26],
                                                show[index].GroupFriendlyName == 'Aydınlatma'
                                                    ? [Colors.yellow, Colors.orange]
                                                    : [
                                                  const Color.fromRGBO(9, 9, 121, 1),
                                                  const Color.fromRGBO(0, 170, 255, 1)
                                                ]
                                              ],
                                              animate: true,
                                              // with just animate set to true, default curve = Curves.easeIn
                                              curve: Curves.bounceInOut,
                                              // animate must be set to true when using custom curve
                                              onToggle: (switchindex) {

                                                if(show[index].GroupFriendlyName=='Aydınlatma'){
                                                  SmartTools.light.forEach((element) {
                                                    if(element.FriendlyName==show[index].FriendlyName){
                                                      element.Status=switchindex;
                                                      HttpService.postSome(MySharedPreferences.token, element.Id, switchindex==0?false:true);

                                                    }
                                                  });
                                                }
                                                else {
                                                  SmartTools.climates.forEach((element) {
                                                    if(element.FriendlyName==show[index].FriendlyName){
                                                      element.Status=switchindex;
                                                      HttpService.postSome(MySharedPreferences.token, element.Id, switchindex==0?false:true);


                                                    }
                                                  });
                                                }
                                                HistoryList.history.add(HistoryList(
                                                  year: DateTime.now().year.toString(),
                                                  month: months[DateTime.now().month-1],
                                                  day: DateTime.now().day<10?'0'+DateTime.now().day.toString():DateTime.now().day.toString(),
                                                  hour: DateTime.now().hour<10?'0'+DateTime.now().hour.toString():DateTime.now().hour.toString(),
                                                  minute: DateTime.now().minute<10?'0'+DateTime.now().minute.toString():DateTime.now().minute.toString(),
                                                  second: DateTime.now().second<10?'0'+DateTime.now().second.toString():DateTime.now().second.toString(),
                                                  name: show[index].FriendlyName,
                                                  service: show[index].GroupFriendlyName,
                                                  svg: show[index].image,
                                                ));
                                              },
                                            );
```

Comment: When you're calling the following  statement `SmartTools.lightsInstance[0]`, there is probability that `lightsInstance` is empty or its element is empty. So, you will have a `x = null`. You need to handle that probability.

Comment: let me explain like this
I call the  `initialLabelindex` function in the widget statement that in future.builder. yes, `SmartTools.lightsInstance[0]` is empty at the beginning but when I get the data with future builder, I direct the data into it. In this case, shouldn't `SmartTools.lightsInstance[0]` come full because the function runs after the data is received?